# android: removing listview selector

Tags: android, listview, colors, selector

I have changed the lsitview selector color to transparent. Even then when I click on the list item, the color of the text changes to dark grey.. is there anyway to handle this issue. I don't want the color to be changed upon item click ..

Comment: Doing this means that users will be unable to use pointing devices to navigate your app. Please reconsider your plan.

Comment: did you set the text color of the text to black or something beforehand in the listview item?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first this problem solution achieve we can create custom listview...

suppose your listview xml file like...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

    <ListView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and custom view xml file...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >
        <TextView 
        android:text="TextView" 
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dip">
        </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and run your application...than you click on item no color show ...

get full code about this problem [click here](http://kundanit.blogspot.com/2011/08/android-removing-listview-selector.html).